# Prove: There is a $g \in G$ such that $\forall$ $x \in X: g \circ x \neq x$

Tags: group-theory, group-actions

I have to prove this theorem for my math study:

Let $G$ be a finite group, and $X$ a set with #$X \geqslant 2$. Let the action of $G$ on $X$ be transitive.

Prove: There is a $g \in G$ such that $\forall$ $x \in X: g \circ x \neq x$

So far, I'm not getting any further than this:

For any $x \in X$, the orbit of x is given by $Gx = ${$g \circ x | g \in G$}. So from the transitive action of $G$ on $X$, we can conclude that #$Gx = 1$

I don't have any idea on how to complete the proof, or if it's actually right what I'm doing. Could you please explain me how to complete the proof?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you know http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burnside%27s_lemma ?

Comment: Thanks for the site, but I don't see how it could help me with solving this problem. If I wanted to use that lemma, I would have to prove it first, and that would be very difficult for me

Comment: If you knew this lemma, you could use it nicely. I just wanted to know what tools you have at your disposal.

Comment: Try calculating the order of the set $\{(x,g)\in X\times G\mid g\circ x = x\}$ in two different ways: Once as sum over the elements of $G$ and once as sum over the elements of $X$.

Comment: Typo: we can conclude that #Gx > 1 is correct.

Comment: I strongly second j.p.'s advice to think about the order of the set $\lbrace (x,g)\in X\times G \mid gx=x\rbrace $.

Answer (score 1):

since $G$ acts transitively on $X$ so $|X/G|=1$... again if we assume there is no such $g \in G$ then  $|X^g| \geq 1$ and $|X^e|=|X|$...then by burnside's lemma (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burnside%27s_lemma) $|X/G| >1$ which is a contradiction.

Comment: Why the upvote? Peter does not know Burnside's lemma (and what's the connection between having no fixed point free element and the fixed points of (which??) $g$ being the whole set? (I see no indication that the $g$ in the exponent is the identity.)).

Comment: This looks better! (And looking at [Peter's last question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1192404/how-many-different-necklaces-of-11-beads-can-you-make-with-m-different-colours) he does know Burnside's lemma.)