# How many different necklaces of 11 beads can you make with $m$ different colours?

Tags: group-theory, graph-theory

I'm having the following problem:

Assume there are $m$ different colours of beads, and you have an infinite amount of beads of each colour. How many different necklaces can you make with 11 beads?

Take $N$ as the amount of different necklaces.

I think I have to use Burnside's Lemma, but I don't no which variables I have to fill in which place. Can you explain me how to compute $N$?

Comment: Looking at results like Burnside's lemma as just an equation to arbitrarily put variables into is not going to be very helpful. Start with considering the problem of making necklaces with 11 labeled positions. Then note that the symmetry of the problem reduces the number of such configurations that are distinct once you remove the labelling; Burnside's Lemma addresses this sort of situation.

Comment: In general whether you use Burnside or the Polya Enumeration Theorem you more or less have to compute the cycle index of the cyclic group on $11$ elements. Note that $11$ is prime however so that simplifies things considerably. This page at [MSE Meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1868/list-of-generalizations-of-common-questions#13335) has a number of useful examples.

Answer (score 1):

You'll be wanting to use the [Cycle index](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CycleIndex.html). Here's an approach to the question which serves as a general recipe for doing something like this.

First, compute the relevant permutation group acting on the object you want to study. In this case, it's a subgroup of the full symmetry group of the necklace on $11$ beads -- so it is a subgroup of $D_{11}$. Let's consider only the cyclic action of $C_{11} \leq D_{11}
$, with its natural action.

The cycle index for a cyclic group $C_n$ is in general $Z(C_n) = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k \mid p} \phi(k) a_k^{p/k}$. But this simplifies dramatically for prime $p$, as you should verify: we have $Z(C_{11}) = \frac{1}{11} (a_{1}^{11} + 10a_{11})$. This essentially says that there is one element of $C_{11}$ which only has $1$-cycles (can you see which one?) and $10$ elements which are $11$-cycles.

More generally, you have to enumerate all elements of your group and write down their cycle structure to find $Z(G)$. You can find this worked out in a few examples in the link above.

Now, you have $m$ different colours of beads. The beautiful thing about the cycle index is that you can now simply substitute $m$ (the number of different coloured beads) for all $a_i$ and you will get the number of $C_{11}$-orbits on this object. Thus the total number of coloured necklaces up to symmetry is $\frac{1}{11}(m^{11} + 10m)$.

The cycle index can do an awful lot more than this, though, especially with regards to figure counting series. For example, you might ask how many colourings, up to symmetry, use exactly $4$ green beads, $6$ blue, and $1$ orange. This is potentially really tricky to do by hand, but the cycle index can be used to compute this explicitly.

Comment: given that necklaces are 3d objects, wouldn't we have to have $D_{11}$ act on the set of coloured necklaces instead of $C_{11}$?

Comment: @Sofia That's what I mention in the second paragraph. Often one only considers the cyclic action for necklaces, but the method works precisely the same for $D_{11}$ instead!

Comment: Yes, that is indeed true

Answer (score 0):

Take 
$X=\{\text{coloured 11-gons}\}$ and $G=C_{11}$

for $g \in G $:

$g=0 : n(g)=m^{11}$ as given no permutations we have $m^{11}$ different necklaces

$g \neq 0: n(g)=m$, as 11 is a prime number

Furthermore, $ord(G)=11$

So by Burnside's thm we have: $\frac{1}{11} (m^{11} +10m) $

Now, we have to consider the fact that a necklace is not just a polygon. To do that we have to take $G=D_{11}$ and follow the above logic.

Answer (score 0):

Let $X=\{ \text{coloured necklases}\}$ and let $D_{11}$ act on $X$.

Then we find the number of fixed points for each element of $D_{11}$

- $n(r^0)=m^{11}$ 
  as when there is no rotation there are m different colour choices for each  of the 11 beads
- For $i \in \{1,2,3...,11\}$ :
  $n(r^i)= m^{\gcd(11,i)}=m$ 
  this can be easily shown as $ < r> $ is cyclic and 11 is a number prime
- For $i \in \{0,1,2,3...,11\} : n(r^is)= m^6$ 
  as when mirroring the necklaces, there are m different colours for 6 sets of beads (5 pairs of beads and 1 independent of the rest)

By Byrnside's Lemma we have:

$ \# orbits = \frac{1}{\# D_{11}}\sum_{g \in D_{11}}{n(g)} = \frac{1}{22} (m^{11} + 10m+11m^6)$